# what is the meaning of ARR DB 5 DUP(2)?

Tags: assembly, emu8086

**ARRAY DB 5 DUP (2)**

what is the meaning of this expression?
what are values inside of ARR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For operators/directives used by MASM (such as `DUP`) you can usually find some form of documentation on MSDN. In this case, the relevant page [is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/is-is/library/3h2ye0a0(v=vs.80).aspx).

As the documentation says:

> `count DUP (initialvalue [[, initialvalue]]...)`
>
> Specifies `count` number of declarations of `initialvalue`.

So `DB 5 DUP (2)` outputs 5 bytes that all have the value 2. `ARRAY` is just a label so that you have an easy way of referring to those bytes elsewhere in your code.